# Interaction with Flask's app from within Flask-Script

Tags: flask, flask-script

I have a flask app running, I want something what can interacts with it. Let me explain it with the next example:

Flask app:

```
from flask import Flask

MyApp = Flask(__name__)

mytext = "Hello World!"

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return mytext

def text_reload():
    global mytext
    mytext = "Hey! I have been reloaded!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp.run()
```

Flask-Script (manager.py):

```
from flask.ext.script import Manager
from myapp import MyApp

manager = Manager(MyApp)

@manager.command
def reload_mytext():
    **DO SOME MAGIC HERE**

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

That `reload_mytext()` calls `text_reload()` function from within the app.

What magic should I put in flask-script to accomplish this stuff? Is such a thing even possible?

Comment: Flask-Script runs in a new process each time you use the command-line; this process is always going to be a separate one from the running server. This means you need some form of interprocess communication, or a shared external database, to achieve what you want to do. What is the goal here, what are you trying to achieve, ultimately?

Comment: I want to create a flask-script scenario which can be called when its needed to make flask app to reload/redefine some variables.

Comment: yeah, i understand that the processes are different. I want to know if there's an API or something which can trigger flask app's methods from outside. a special route would solve the problem, but may be there's something internal.. I don't know.

Comment: There is nothing pre-coded for you; a special route would be the easiest way to go about this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thanks. I'm going to look at interprocess communication -- this is what I really want :)

Answer (score 0):

I think app.app_context() is what you are looking for.
But you need to make the context first like.

```
def _make_context():
    return dict(app=app, db=db, models=models)

manager = Manager(create_app)
manager.add_command("livereload", liveReloadServer, Shell(make_context=_make_context))
```

and then:

```
class liveReloadServer(Command):
    """prints hello world"""
    def run(self):
        with app.app_context():
            server = Server(app.wsgi_app)
            app.config['LIVERELOAD'] = True
            server.serve(port=8080)
```